# Session error using Laravel PHP

Tags: php, session, laravel

I get this error when enabling sessions, using the filesystem, in Laravel PHP.

```
Only variables should be passed by reference in SYS_PATH/session.php on line 230.

Stack Trace:
0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/system/session.php(230): System\{closure}(2048, 'Only variables ...', '/Applications/X...', 230, Array)

1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/system/session.php(190): System\Session::write_cookie()

2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/system/laravel.php(187): System\Session::close()

3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/public/index.php(44): require('/Applications/X...')

4 {main}

Snapshot:
225:     */
226:    private static function write_cookie()
227:    {
228:        if ( ! headers_sent())
229:        {
230:            extract(Config::get('session'));
231: 
232:            $minutes = ($expire_on_close) ? 0 : $lifetime;
233: 
234:            Cookie::put('laravel_session', static::$session['id'], $minutes, $path, $domain, $https, $http_only);
235:        }
```

Has anybody run into this issue? Even if you don't use Laravel, any insight?

Comment: Which version of the Laravel framework are you referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That you're seeing the error message is a *flaw* in the Laravel PHP framework.

The session class makes use of the [`extract` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) that is expecting a variable, but it get's a function return.

I have [reported this behavior](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/67) to the project and you can discuss the options with them as well. You find a suggestion how to fix it attached, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of extracting the config to your local scope you just assign it to an array, and use those values? The error seems to be there, not with sessions.